# Update quantities in one model with sum of quantities in another

Tags: python, django

I have two models that need to match on 2 fields using a .filter method. 
Model B only has 1 unique code, while Model A can have that code multiple times with multiple quantities. So Model B quantity should be the sum for every occurrence of the code in Model A
I believe I found the right way to match the fields and get the quantity_sum, but I am unsure of how to add the quantity_sum to the related code in Model B

```
class ModelA():
    code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class ModelB():
    code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def update_quantity(self):
        #calculate sum of quantity from ModelA()
        sum_quantity = ModelA.objects.filter(
            department=self.department,
            code=self.code
        ).aggregate(
            quantity_sum=Sum(F('quantity'))
        )

        #define save ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
class ModelB():
    code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def update_quantity(self):
        #calculate sum of quantity from ModelA()
        sum_quantity = ModelA.objects.filter(
            department=self.department,
            code=self.code
        ).aggregate(
            quantity_sum=Sum(F('quantity'))
        )

        self.quantity = sum_quantity["quantity_sum"]
        self.save()
```